# Foreach dentro do while na saida do Json

Tags: php, mysql

Estou buscando faz uns dias como fazer um foreach dentro de um while para imprimir no json os dados relacionados a essa consulta. Meu cenário é esse:

```
<?php
require_once('../Connections/db.php');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$tabelabd = "carros";

$con = @mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db, $database_db);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carros WHERE idusuario='1' AND ativo='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$var[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"'.$tabelabd.'":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
```

A saida do Json disso é:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "idusuario":"1",
      "data_cadastro":"2015-09-11",
      "ativo":"S",
      "titulo":"Gol 2009",
      "galeria":"20",
      "destaque":"S"
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "idusuario":"1",
      "data_cadastro":"2015-09-11",
      "ativo":"S",
      "titulo":"Ford Ka 2002",
      "galeria":"21",
      "destaque":"S"
   }
]

// PRECISO QUE A SAIDA SEJA COM A LISTA DE FOTOS(FOREACH) ASSIM:

[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "idusuario":"1",
      "data_cadastro":"2015-09-11",
      "ativo":"S",
      "titulo":"Gol 2009",
      "cor":"Prata",
      "galeria":[  
         {  
            "foto_id":1,
            "opcional_nome":"Foto 01"
         },
         {  
            "foto_id":2,
            "opcional_nome":"Foto 03"
         },
         {  
            "foto_id":3,
            "opcional_nome":"Foto 03"
         }
      ],
      "destaque":"S",
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "idusuario":"1",
      "data_cadastro":"2015-09-11",
      "ativo":"S",
      "titulo":"Ford Ka 2002",
      "galeria":[  
         {  
            "foto_id":7,
            "opcional_nome":"Foto 01"
         }
      ],
      "destaque":"S",
   }
]
```

Alguém poderia me instruir como fazer essa consulta? Minha tabela é "Galeria" e possui a listagem de fotos e cada uma é guardada com um id de relacionamento (no caso, aquele id que hoje consigo imprimir no Json).

Comment: Fala Fábio, tudo bom? Olha, de certa forma isto é simples demais, porém seria interessante você nos passar o seu schema do banco, para poder implementar um exemplo de código para você. Seria interessante você enviar para gente via sqlfiddle.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro do WHILE(), para cada carro você precisa fazer uma nova consulta na tabela galeria e incluir estes objetos no do carro. Um exemplo:

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $sql_galeria = "SELECT * FROM galeria WHERE idcarro='". $obj->id ."'";
    $result_galeria = mysqli_query($con, $sql_galeria);
    while ($galeria = mysqli_fetch_object($result_galeria)) {
        $obj->galeria[] = $galeria;
    }
    $var[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"'.$tabelabd.'":'.json_encode($var).'}';
```

- Corrigi a partir do seu comentário.

Comment: Acrescentei apenas o fechamento do parênteses ali depois do ($result_galeria)) e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado NewtonWagner